# How to iterate over these embedded values in Tridion DWT template

Tags: tridion

My XML is something like this.

```xml
.
.
.
</body>

<List>
  <topicTitle>This is topic title</topicTitle>
  <topDef>This is topic definition.</topDef>
</List>
```

I basically want to insert `topicTitle` and `topDef` into `<li>` tags. And I am trying to do so with this code (code for topicTitle shown only for simplicity):

```html
<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="List" -->

    <!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="Field.topicTitle" -->

        <li>@@RenderComponentField(FieldPath+".value", 
                                   TemplateRepeatIndex)@@ </li>
    <!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->

<!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas?

Comment: Is this XML based on a Tridion web schema (so with an embedded schema named List)? Or is this something you have in a rich-text field?

Comment: Also: what do you get as output? And what are the values your see for "(FieldPath=@@FieldPath@@, TemplateRepeatIndex=@@TemplateRepeatIndex@@)" (as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10322575/209103)?

Comment: This <!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="Field.topicTitle" --> will only iterate over the topicTitle field's values - doesn't seem at all like what you want to do...

Answer (score 1):

In case of embeddable schema you don't need to iterate over xmlList (with TemplateBeginRepeat) unlike Component link, here you can directly access the embedded child element via syntax:-

@@Component.XMLNameOfEmbeddedschema.XmlElementNameinEmbeddedSchema@@

pls note in above XMLNameOfEmbeddedschema = the XMLName you give in parent schema while inserting an embeddable schema.

So in your scenario it will work with

@@Component.List.topicTitle@@ for accessing value of topicTitle.

Please mark this answer as accepted, if this solution works for you...